# query and manipulation of TFS build server agent status

Tags: tfs, msbuild, tfsbuild

I'm trying to manipulate the status of a build agent using the TFS build extensions.  the QueryBuildAgentStatus and SetBuildAgentStatus look identical and the query activity doesn't have a result parameter.
How do I query the build agent status and change it?

-Thanks

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using? Do you mean you use TfsBuildExtensions at https://github.com/flcdrg/TfsBuildExtensions?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using XAML Build, I tried to monitor the build agent status in `[Tfs_DefaultCollection].[dbo].[tbl_BuildAgent]` in TFS database.

If the build agent is **Ready**, you can see the **Status** and **Enabled** in tbl_BuildAgent is "**1**" and "**1**". If you **disable** the build agent, you can see the **Status** and **Enabled** in tbl_BuildAgent is "**1**" and "**0**". If you **stop** build service with build agent enabled, then the build agent is stop too, you can see the **Status** and **Enabled** in tbl_BuildAgent is "**2**" and "**1**".

So generally speaking, XAML build agent has **Ready** and **Stop** status (not sure what do you want to change). If you want to stop the build agent, just stop the build service.

Here is a [LinqPad query to get Build agents status and build queue](http://pascallaurin42.blogspot.sg/2012/06/tfs-queries-build-agents-status-and.html), you may take a look at it:

```
var tfs = TfsTeamProjectCollectionFactory
 .GetTeamProjectCollection(new Uri("http://localhost:8088/tfs"));

tfs.EnsureAuthenticated();

var buildServer = tfs.GetService<IBuildServer>();

var queryAgents = buildServer.QueryBuildAgents(buildServer.CreateBuildAgentSpec());
queryAgents.Agents
 .Select(x => new
 {
  x.MachineName,
  Controller = x.Controller.Name,
  x.Enabled,
  x.Status,
  x.QueueCount
 })
 .Dump("TFS build agents");

queryAgents.Agents
 .SelectMany(x => ServiceController.GetServices(x.ServiceHost.Name)
  .Where(s => s.ServiceName.StartsWith("TFSBuildServiceHost")))
 .Select(x => new
 {
  x.MachineName,
  x.ServiceName,
  x.Status
 })
 .Dump("Windows Services of build agents");

buildServer
 .QueryQueuedBuilds(buildServer.CreateBuildQueueSpec("*"))
 .QueuedBuilds
 .Select(x => new
 {
  x.TeamProject,
  BuildDefinition = x.BuildDefinition.Name,
  x.QueuePosition,
  x.QueueTime,
  x.Priority,
  x.CustomGetVersion,
  x.RequestedFor,
  x.Reason,
  x.Status
 })
 .OrderBy(x => x.QueuePosition)
 .Dump("Queued builds");
```